# Successful createOrReplaceInventoryItem (inventory_item) call, but where is the item? (eBay API)

Tags: postman, ebay-api

I created an item using this [documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/createOrReplaceInventoryItem).

I retrieved it again using this [documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/getInventoryItem).

All the information I put in was successfully retrieved. So... where is it?

If I log into my account (steps below) I can't see it anywhere.

1. I visit `https://www.ebay.com.au/`
2. I click "sign in" (top left, next to my name)
3. My password is auto-filled. I click "sign in" (Yes, it's exactly the same username I used to mint the authorisation)
4. I click "My eBay" `-->` "Selling/Sold"
5. I click "Listings"

After those steps, I must have clicked every link and button on that page. The listing I created cannot be found anywhere.

Where is it?

(If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know. I will add it in an edit.)

Comment: Are you sure that you are not creating this Item in a Sandbox environment?

Comment: @Dantio Completely certain. The sandbox url path is completely different. It always has the word "sandbox" in it. But thanks for trying. You've shown more effort into this than eBay staff so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating an inventory item you have to [create](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/offer/methods/createOffer) AND [publish](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/offer/methods/publishOffer) an offer for the item to be listed on eBay.

Comment: That was information I willingly paid USD$75 to eBay to have them not tell me.

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers Yeah, I've dealt with those guys too. Good luck.

Comment: I just got off chat with customer service, to ask them how postage works. I must have spent an hour explaining to them they were wrong, and how postage really works when I realised the roles had reversed.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was about to jump out the window!